# How to get a random item from a list in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

If I have a list like:

```
["apples" "pears" "oranges"]
```

What is the the easiest way to get a random item from here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[rand-nth](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/rand-nth) should do the trick:

```
user> (rand-nth ["apples" "pears" "oranges"])
"pears"
user> (rand-nth ["apples" "pears" "oranges"])
"oranges"
user> (rand-nth ["apples" "pears" "oranges"])
"oranges"
```